# Problem with ragged lines

Tags: horizontal-alignment, formatting

Somehow, the lines in my document are all ragged, i.e. the further use of `\raggedright` does not change the document. I do not know the command to undo this (I believe not ragged is the preset). Here are the packages I'm using, could it be one of them responsible for this?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage[letterpaper]{geometry}

\geometry{top=1.35in, bottom=1.35in, left=1.35in, right=1.35in}

\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{float}

\doublespacing

\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage{lineno}
```

Comment: Please post complete code starting from `\documentclass{...}.... `and ending at `\end{document}`. None of these packages shown above cause the effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This is just guessing from very scarce information in the question.)

`\raggedright` is not a "switch", which toggles ragged typesetting and justified typesetting.  If you want to restrict the raggedness to some part of the document, you can:

I. Say

```
\par
{\raggedright
...
\par
}
```

i.e., enclose `\raggedright` in a group (and end a paragraph before TeX gets the "old" values of paragraph-setting parameters).

II. Say

```
\par
\begin{raggedright}
...
\par
\end{raggedright}
```

which works (due to the way environments are defined in LaTeX2e), but is *very* inelegant (and requires \par at the end).  (Here and further, `\par` may be of course replaced by a blank line, i.e., two consecutive newlines, possibly with intervening spaces (more or less)).

III. Say (in the preamble) something along the lines of:

```
\newenvironment{raggedrightenv}{\par\raggedright}{\par}
```

and use

```
\begin{raggedrightenv}
...
\end{raggedrightenv}
```

(This defines a new environment, which issues `\raggedright` at the beginning and `\par` at the end; an environment always creates a group, so changes to parameters are local.)  This is probably the second-best option.

IV. Say (in the preamble)

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
```

and use

```
\par\raggedright % or \RaggedRight for a bit better effect!
...
\par\justifying
```

V. Say (in the preamble)

```
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newenvironment{RaggedRightenv}{\par\RaggedRight}{\par}
```

and use

```
\begin{RaggedRightenv}
...
\end{RaggedRightenv}
```

This is imho the best option.